# lambda expression map according to filter in java

Tags: java, lambda

How to a map a part of a collection using lambda according to a certain filter?

I have a list of integers and I want to time by 2 the odd integer and keep the even one as they are how to do this using lambda ex

```
int [] d={1,2,3,4,5};
result={2,2,6,4,10};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
Arrays.stream(d).map(x -> x % 2 == 0 ? x : 2 * x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(d).map(number -> number = ((number & 1) == 1 ? number * 2 : number)).toArray();
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
```